# Notice: Undefined index: Ans in C:\wamp64\www\quiz\remove\repeated.php on line 13

Tags: php, mysql

How to resolve this?

> Notice: Undefined index: Ans in C:\wamp64\www\quiz\remove\repeated.php on line 13

My code:

```
require_once '../class.user.php';
$user_home = new USER();
$lstmtf = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT COUNT(Ans)
FROM answer AS a
LEFT JOIN students_records AS s ON a.Sr = s.Sr
WHERE s.Sr IS NULL");
    $lstmtf->execute();
$reg_rst = $lstmtf->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$registered= $reg_rst['Ans'];
        echo $registered;
```

My table **answer** has column name `Ans`.

Actually, I want to count the numbers of rows which do not have values in `students_records`.

For Eg:

**students_records**

```
+----+-----+-----+ 
| Sr | SRN | ARN |
+----+-----+-----+
| 1  | ge  | aj  |
| 2  | ge  | bd  |
+----+-----+-----+
```

**answer**

```
+----+-----+-----+
| Sr | SRN | ARN |
+----+-----+-----+
| 1  | ge  | aj  |
| 2  | ge  | aj  |
| 3  | ge  | ne  |
| 4  | ge  | bd  |
+----+-----+-----+
```

Here count should be **1**. As the value "ne" in column `ARN` of table answer is no where in the rows of column `ARN` in table students_records.

Comment: change `SELECT *, COUNT(Ans)` or `COUNT(Ans) as Ans`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: @urfusion if I write `COUNT(Ans) as Ans` it gives me the result, but it counts all row. But I want to count only rows which do not have value in table `students_records`

Comment: @urfusion I have also edited the question!

Comment: The question is being edited! @Jens

Comment: change your where condition `s.ARN != a.ARN`

Comment: @urfusion the result is **0**.

Comment: CAn you create your tables on http://sqlfiddle.com and share it in your question.

Comment: @urfusion [Somehow like this?](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c07fd0/1)

Comment: Yes, Let me check that now.

Comment: try this
`SELECT a.*
FROM answer AS a
LEFT JOIN students_records AS s ON a.ARN = s.ARN
WHERE   s.ARN IS NULL`

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c07fd0/46

Comment: @PBMusics : check the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the desire output by following

```
SELECT count(a.Ans) as ans
FROM answer AS a
LEFT JOIN students_records AS s ON a.ARN = s.ARN
WHERE   s.ARN IS NULL
```

Here is working [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c07fd0/46)

Comment: If I want to delete all those rows from the answer, what will be the code? can you please edit your answer and add more code which works for deletion... A request.

Comment: Can you please help me with it.

Comment: You want to do that in 1 query or can write another query after getting results?

Comment: I want to delete all that queries, meaning if there are 5 all 5 should be deleted!

Comment: `DELETE a
FROM answer AS a
LEFT JOIN students_records AS s ON a.ARN = s.ARN
WHERE   s.ARN IS NULL`

Comment: @PBMusics : check the query.

Comment: Yes, looked and I will try to execute it as I get time, thanks a lot

Comment: Sorry to disturb can you please have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47485738/how-do-i-remove-pma-tables-from-mysql-without-affecting-other-tables

Answer (score 1):

Use like this

```
$lstmtf = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT COUNT(Ans) as Ans
FROM answer AS a
LEFT JOIN students_records AS s ON a.Sr = s.Sr
WHERE s.Sr IS NULL");
```

Comment: Can you please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47454098/notice-undefined-index-ans-in-c-wamp64-www-quiz-remove-repeated-php-on-line-1#comment81862902_47454098